# Could I get Status Shopping Cart in magento from anywhere

Tags: magento, shopping-cart

Let me know how can I get status of shopping cart in magento from anywhere ?

I mean that Is It possible to get an error like 
- your `item "marlboro" count has been exceeded` ! At present .
There is no so much in stock, please decrease it

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like that on an event that is fired on every page like controller_front_init_before

```
$cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
foreach ($cart->getAllItems() as $item) {
    $product = $item->getProduct();
    $stocklevel = (int)Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')
         ->loadByProduct($product)->getQty();
    if ($stocklevel<$item->getQty()){
         ...the logic that will permit to show the customer that the requested 
         product is not avaiable in this quantity...   
    }
}
```